# Curl connect to server issue(facebook api)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

The error I'm getting is:

> Curl error: couldn't connect to hostCurl error: couldn't connect to
>   host

I have tried almost everything to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to work file_get_contents doesn't work either but its enabled.

```
         $response = curl_exec($ch);

         if($response === false) {
             echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
         } else {
             $response = $response;
         }         

         curl_close($ch);
         return $response;
     }
     $app_id = "APP_ID"; 
     $app_secret = "APP_SECRET"; 
     $fanpage_id ='325145047546976';
     $post_login_url = "http://www.feriajanos.com/src/teszt.php";  
     $photo_url = "http://www.feriajanos.com/kepek/mas/posztok/poszt20130412104817.jpg";
     $photo_caption = "Feri A János";
     $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
     if (!$code) { 
        $dialog_url= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
          . "client_id=" .  $app_id
          . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
          .  "&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";

        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
          . "'</script>");
     } 
     if(isset($_REQUEST['code'] )) {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
          . "client_id=" . $app_id
          . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
          . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
          . "&code=" . $code;


        $response = curl($token_url);

        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

        // POST to Graph API endpoint to upload photos
        $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
          . "url=" . urlencode($photo_url)
          . "&message=" . urlencode($photo_caption)
          . "&method=POST"
          . "&access_token=" .$access_token;

        echo '<html><body>';

           echo curl($graph_url);

        echo '</body></html>';
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with your server not being able to reach Facebook's servers or the server hosting 'http://www.feriajanos.com' - it's likely a problem with your server, network or PHP configuration

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook picture uploader (fanpage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452652/facebook-picture-uploader-fanpage)

Comment: you know, they call it a **SECRET** key for a reason